# Azure Search RetryPolicy

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

We are using azure search and need to implement a retry stratgey as well as storing the Ids of failed documents as described.

Is there any documentation/samples on how to implement a RetryPolicy strategy in Azure Search.

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring specifically to retrying when the Index API throws IndexBatchException? For all other cases, the .NET SDK already uses a default retry policy with exponential backoff.

Comment: @brucejohnston Yes. As far as we can tell the default policy is for 500 errors but not if things like load issues cause a failure.

Comment: Yes, you need to handle IndexBatchException explicitly. To clarify -- what do you mean by "storing" the IDs of failed documents? Do you mean persisting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I used:

```
 private async Task<DocumentIndexResult> IndexWithExponentialBackoffAsync(IndexBatch<IndexModel> indexBatch)
 {
      return await Policy
           .Handle<IndexBatchException>()
           .WaitAndRetryAsync(5, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)), (ex, span) =>
           {
                indexBatch = ((IndexBatchException)ex).FindFailedActionsToRetry(indexBatch, x => x.Id);
           })
           .ExecuteAsync(async () => await _searchClient.IndexAsync(indexBatch));
 }
```

It uses the [Polly library](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) to handle exponential backoff. In this case I use a model `IndexModel` that has a id field named `Id`.
If you like to log or store the ids of the failed attempts you can do that in the `WaitAndRetryAsync` function like

```
((IndexBatchException)ex)ex.IndexingResults.Where(r => !r.Succeeded).Select(r => r.Key).<Do something here>
```

Comment: I've taken this example as the start to incorporate [other suggestions by Bruce in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61506998/590790). I added a retry as long as there is progress and exponential backoff only up to 1 minute, after which the delay is constant.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no sample showing how to properly retry on `IndexBatchException`. However, there is a method you can use to make it easier to implement: [IndexBatchException.FindFailedActionsToRetry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.azure.search.indexbatchexception.findfailedactionstoretry.aspx). This method extracts the IDs of failed documents from the IndexBatchException, correlates them with the actions in a given batch, and returns a new batch containing only the failed actions that need to be retried.

Regarding the rest of the retry logic, you might find this code in the [ClientRuntime library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/AutoRest/src/ClientRuntime/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime/TransientFaultHandling) useful. You will need to tweak the parameters based on the characteristics of your load. The important thing to remember is that you should use exponential backoff before retrying to help your service recover, since otherwise your requests may be throttled.