# Azure search FindFailedActionsToRetry returning empty actions?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I was testing the `FindFailedActionsToRetry` function on c# client for azure search and I am not getting expected results.

In my function I try to index the batch and i have a try-catch that handles IndexBatchException. 
Inside the catch I do:

`var retryBatch = e.FindFailedActionsToRetry(batch, id => id["Identifier"].ToString());`

The first time I index I get: 
 `999 out of the 1000 documents failed to index` (which is expected).

Then I try to index the batch again but instead of getting the same `indexbatchexception` thrown out (because I purposedly set `merge` as the action of the original 1k documents), I get another exception:

`The request is invalid. Details: actions : No indexing actions found in the request. Please include between 1 and 1000 indexing actions in your request.`

Any ideas why the `FindFailedActionsToRetry` function is not returning correct results? or maybe im doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

To show more context, when I expand the `retrybatch` object I created which contains an `IndexBatch` object, I can see `Actions`. I then Expand further, click on results view, and I get: `Enumeration yielded no results`

The original batch That I sent the first time **did** have resutls. In fact, I could see: Action,document. Action,document, etc.

Why am I not seing any results?

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? In the call to `FindFailedActionsToRetry`, what type is `id`?

Comment: I am using 3.0.3.  I started by using the findfailedactionstoretry with no Type so I just said "Identifier" which is my key field in azure search. That didn't work so I used the Typed version which also didn't work. id is a Document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are provoking an indexing failure in a way that is not transient and therefore not retriable. `FindFailedActionsToRetry` is smart enough to detect this. Take a look at the `ShouldRetry` method [in the code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/psSdkJson6/src/SDKs/Search/DataPlane/Microsoft.Azure.Search/Customizations/IndexBatchException.cs).

Comment: Wao, took me a long time to find that. Thanks a lot. I was getting 404 which is not retriable as you mentioned. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah, sorry for suggesting this method. I forgot that `FindFailedActionsToRetry` takes retry-ability into account.