# Azure search - connection timeout

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I've had a couple of random instances in a 1 hour period, of the Azure Search service returning a connection timeout, it is being called from a .net core web application running as an Azure App Service.

App Insights has a dependency failure for the same time (a POST to /indexes('products')/docs/search.post.search?api-version=2019-05-06) with a response of "Faulted".

Any help/idea on why this happened and how I can prevent would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could be attempting to retrieve too much data at once. Or you may have a throttling issue because of too much traffic. The reason for the timeout is not possible to determine without more context.

To avoid timeouts, you could optimize and resolve your root cause by reducing the response size, limiting the number of requests, or addressing your issue's root cause.

Also, consider implementing a retry mechanism with exponential backoff. See this thread for information: [Azure Search .net SDK- How to use "FindFailedActionsToRetry"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012885/azure-search-net-sdk-how-to-use-findfailedactionstoretry/40028593)

Comment: But I hit refresh, multiple times and it was only the 1 that failed

Comment: Requests may fail. No network or service can provide 100% uptime. If having one random failed request is an issue for your application, you have to design for it by using redundancy and retries.

Answer (score 0):

As Dan mentioned, it is recommended to use retries since failures due to network or many other reasons can happen and this will help improve your app availability. However, if you are seeing failures happen repeatedly or need more information then please open a support issue so the support team can investigate it further.